# How do I get the diagonals to work in 5 x 5 tic tac toe?

Tags: java

The first line of the code is for the top left to bottom right diagonal and that works perfectly, the second line is the bottom left to top right and I can't seem to get it working. Here is an idea of the tic tac toe game and the arrays.

```java
if (((check[0][0] == check[1][1]) && (check[0][0] == check[2][2]) && (check[0][0] == check[3][3]) && (check[0][0] == check[4][4])) ||
    ((check[1][1] == check[4][0]) && (check[1][1] == check[3[1]))){
    
    if (check[1][1] == 1)) { //if player x wins
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the winner");
        gameEnd = true;
        winner = 1;
    } else if (check[1][1] == 2){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the winner");
        gameEnd = true;
        winner = 2;
    }
    
}
```

[Tic Tac Toe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8R98.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't know

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as actual well-formatted code. [Ask] is one of the pages you've been pointed to when you tried to post that question and it pretty clearly tells you not to post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a loop.

```
int matches = 0;
for(int i=1; i++; i<5){
    if (check[0][0] == check[i][i]) 
        matches++;
}

if (matches == 4){
    if (check[1][1] == 1)){ }
    if (check[1][1] == 2)){ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to check generically for any size SQUARE board:

```
int d1Value = 0;
int d2Value = 0;
boolean diagonal1 = true;
boolean diagonal2 = true;
for(int row=0, colA=0, colB=check[0].length-1; row<check.length && (diagonal1 || diagonal2); row++, colA++, colB--) {
    if (row==0) {
      d1Value = check[row][colA];
      d2Value = check[row][colB];
      diagonal1 = (d1Value!=0);  
      diagonal2 = (d2Value!=0);  
    }
    else {
      diagonal1 = diagonal1 && (check[row][colA]==d1Value);
      diagonal2 = diagonal2 && (check[row][colB]==d2Value);
    }
}
String winner = null;
if (diagonal1) {
  winner = (d1Value == 1) ? "X" : "Y";
}
else if (diagonal2) {
  winner = (d2Value == 1) ? "X" : "Y";
}
if (winner != null) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, winner + " is the winner");  
}
```